# Is there any good algorithm implementation that can find nearest negative elements from specific array elements?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, search, time-complexity

I am currently working on C programming, and when current index is defined as int variable **idx**, I need to find the nearest negative element in range of [0, idx-1] from idx in array.

For example, If array is **1 -2 3 -4 5 6** and **idx** is 5 (array[idx] will be 6), function has to return **3**, as **-4** is the nearest negative element from array[idx].

I know how to solve this problem linearly, like

```
for(int i = idx-1; i>=0; i--){
   if(array[i] < 0) return i;
}
```

but I want to know faster algorithm (which means the algorithm that has lower time complexity) because I am currently working on big-sized arrays that have elements more than million. Can somebody help?

Comment: O(N) is best case but If the array doesn't change, you could cache results. Searching an array with a million elements once isn't too bad.

Comment: I have to execute this function while iterating array(idx is a iterator of the array), so the overall complexity should be O(n^2). But I guess I don't have any choice :(

Comment: @Martin Jones "unction has to return 3, as -4 " Why not 1 as -2?

Comment: Does the array change while you're iterating over it? If not then just remeber the index of the last negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bit array *once* setting one bit for each index containing a negative number. If you store this bit array as 64 bit unsigned integers, you can check 64 indexes at the same time.

If you have 100 million entries, and one in 10,000 are negative only, you can create a second bit array setting one bit for each 64 bit number in the first array. So checking *one* array element in that array allows you to check 4096 entries simultaneously.

It's a bit more code of course. It's faster when negative numbers are rare.

If you have to do this while iterating through an array, that makes it much more easy. Just remember the last result. Say you found that the negative number closest to index 500,000 was at index 493,005. Now you want the negative number closest to index 500,001. Where could it be? It could be at index 500,000, and if that number is not negative, then it is again at #493,005. Trivial to calculate in O(n) for all i, not O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

O(N) is the best that can be done without additional information. Consider an array that contains no negative values. The only way to determine that is to visit the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is very large and negative numbers are sparse, you might get faster execution by OR-ing chunks of 8 or 16 numbers and comparing the result to `0`. A positive or zero result means none of these numbers are negative, and a negative result means these is at least one, which you can find with a simpler loop (no boundary condition).

This method produces fewer tests and OR-ing blocks of array elements can compile to vectorized code, so the performance should be better, but the complexity stays the same: linear time. Careful benchmarking will tell if this is worthwhile given your data sets.